# HTML header appears twice when check page source code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a strange issue with my work.
While I do test on my local host of my web project while doing page source check i am getting following:

```
   <!DOCTYPE    html>   
  <html>    
  <head>    
            <meta   charset="UTF-8">    
            <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>    
  </head>   
  <body>    
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
 <head>   
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/style.css" />
</head>
  <body>
```

Doctype seems to appear twice. But in my actual code it is only

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
 <head>   
   <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/style.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
```

Any ideas why could it happen? I have created project in Visual Studio. 
Thanks

Comment: can u share your actual code ?? I mean dynamic code

Comment: Are you using a master page?

Comment: Nope. there is no php involved

Comment: may be you have included your `masterpage` twice..

Comment: please refine your code

Comment: Please provide the actual source code for the page in question.

Comment: my code is here: jsfiddle.net/nLyqK

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which may or may not apply to your case.

In my case, I had index.html which started like this..

```
<!--#include virtual="/common/incl/html.incl" -->
<head>
```

In html.incl I defined the doctype amongst other things..

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 8]><html class="no-js ie lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie ie8 lt-ie9" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="no-js ie ie9" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"><!--<![endif]-->
```

But when the source was generated it was generating a duplicate doctype appearing after the conditional comments.

When I removed the doctype declaration from the `.incl` file and instead declared it in the `.html` file BEFORE the include then it resolved the issue.  `.html` documents are required to start with a document type declaration so since I was not initially defining one in the `.html` file, but rather in the `.incl` file, something else in my workflow was adding it for me.